# SQL Query to display heirarchical data

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursive-query

I have two tables - 'Users' and 'Supervision'

For this example, my users table is very simple:-

```
Users
=====
ID (PK)
UserName
```

Some users manage other users, so I've built a second table 'Supervision' to manage this:-

```
Supervision
===========
UserID
SuperID - this is the ID of the staff member that the user supervises.
```

This table is used to join the Users table to itself to identify a particular users supervisor.  It might be that a user has more than one supervisor, so this table works perfectly to this end.

Here's my sample data in 'Users':-

```
userID  userName
1       Bob
2       Margaret
3       Amy
4       Emma
5       Carol
6       Albert
7       Robert
8       Richard
9       Harry
10      Arthur
```

And my data in 'Supervision':-

```
userID  superID
1       2
1       3
2       4
2       5
3       4
3       5
6       1
6       7
7       8
7       9
9       10
```

If I want to see who directly reports to Bob, writing an SQL query is straightforward, and tells me that Margaret and Amy are his direct reports.

What I want to do however is to write a query that shows everybody who comes under Bob, so it would need to look at Bobs direct reports, and then their direct reports, and so on - it would give Margaret, Amy, Emma and Carol as the result in this case.

I'm assuming this requires some kind of recursion but I'm completely stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH RCTE AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Supervision WHERE UserID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.* FROM dbo.Supervision s 
        INNER JOIN RCTE r ON s.userID = r.superID
)
SELECT DISTINCT u.userID, u.userName 
FROM RCTE r
LEFT JOIN dbo.Users u ON r.superID = u.userID
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c100f/1)**

Comment: Does this take into account who manages who below, this only seems to bring back 4 results?

Comment: @SelectDistinct Of course. There are only 4 results in that example. Try running it for user 6 who is on top of hierarchy and you will get all 9 other users below him. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c100f/2

Comment: Ah I see, does my answer do the same thing? I created tables based on the OP's examples and the results were around the 20 mark which is why I became confused

Comment: @SelectDistinct Yes, I've checked your answer. It's ok - you are just missing `WHERE UserID = 1` condition in first part of CTE - so you are getting all possible combinations of users and supervisors instead of just people below one given user. - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/745a8/4

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, I thought all combinations were required!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need a Recursive CTE. This article serves as a primer, and includes a fairly similar example to the one you have:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH MyCTE
AS ( 

-- ID's and Names
SELECT SuperID, ID
FROM Users
join dbo.Supervision
on ID = dbo.Supervision.UserID
WHERE UserID = 1

UNION ALL

--Who Manages who...
SELECT s.SuperID, ID
FROM Supervision s
INNER JOIN MyCTE ON s.UserID = MyCTE.SuperID
WHERE s.UserID IS NOT NULL 

)

SELECT distinct MyCTE.ID, NAMES.UserName, '<------Reports to ' as Hierarchy, res_name.UserName
FROM MyCTE
join dbo.Users NAMES on 
MyCTE.ID = NAMES.ID 

join dbo.Users res_name 
on res_name.ID = MyCTE.SuperID

order by MyCTE.ID, NAMES.UserName, res_name.UserName
```